# Buying games across countries with GameTreeOnline

Tags: region-lock

I am currently sitting in Sydney for a summer break and I want to buy games from GameTreeOnline.  Unfortunately, their 'security' mechanisms prevent me from using my bank account while in Sydney, though they would let me purchase if I were willing to do a cross country transaction with an Australian bank account, so it would be legal.  However, I can ask my friend to purchase it on my account for me.  Now I am curious if said sites would allow me to purchase in the US and then turn around and download from Australia, or would they block my download (in which case my money would be wasted because the main reason I'm buying the game is to play it over the next month).

So, precis:

Can I have my friend in the states buy the game from GameTreeOnline and then download the game in Australia?

Answer (score 1):

Their website says you can use Paypal for payment -- what is preventing you from doing that? They don't know where the money comes from when you use Paypal, so I don't see a problem with that.

As for paying via a friend, I don't see anything in their Terms and Conditions indicating that there would be a problem with that. If you are concerned though, I would suggest contacting them. They do state that they have IP range bans in place to protect their system and suggest contacting them if you are in one of those ban ranges. It's impossible to tell if you are until you try downloading.